# Deploy a MEAN stack application to an existing server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, mean-stack, digital-ocean

I have a Ubuntu Server on DigitalOcean which hosts a website, and a Windows Server on AWS which hosts another website.

I just built a `mean.js` stack app on my MAC, and I plan to deploy it to production.

It seems that most of the existing threads discuss about using a new dedicated server. For example, [this thread](http://programmersdiary.com/node/deploy-mean-stack-app-on-amazon-ec2/) is about deploying on a new AWS EC2 instance; [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5fvd2xdnY8) is about deploying on a new Windows Azure server; [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-host-a-mean-stack-app-on-digital-ocean) is to create a new droplet in DigitalOcean.

My question is, is it possible to use an existing server (which hosts other websites), rather than creating a new server? If yes, will there be any difference in terms of performance?

Comment: why not dockerizing your app and running the container in the host that serves the other websites? docker is cheap and highly configurable but more importantly portable.

Comment: I don't know docker... Actually I don't need to move the app very often, so its advantage of portability is not very appealing to me...

Comment: Well docker handles performance very well and it is not hard to dockerize a node app, here is a very straight forward tutorial:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

I think it is perfect for running several apps in a single server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, is it possible to use an existing server (which hosts other websites), rather than creating a new server?

Yes. Both Windows and Ubuntu allows you to deploy multiple applications on same instance.

For Ubuntu you can read [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-node-js-applications-on-a-single-vps-with-nginx-forever-and-crontab) post which will help you server multiple apps.
In this example used Nginx, but you can follow to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04) example and use it without any server like Apache or Nginx. If you need subdomains I would suggest to use Apache virtual hosts with reverse proxy module and `pm2`

For Windows and its IIS I would suggest to use [`iisnode`](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode), in google you can find a lot of articles how to configure it.

> will there be any difference in terms of performance?

It is depended on your applications, if you are already serving applications which handles huge traffic and need CPU and memory, I would not suggest you to use multiple apps on same instance, but if you are going to use simple web apps, you can easily use same instance.

Hope this answer will help you!